# List content of folder and child subfolders using CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, parent-child, cakephp-2.x

I am trying to get content of folder and sub folders content in php mysql.
I have build a table to maintain folder structure as follows

[image: image1]

And another table for media contents of the folder, which is as follows

[image: Image2]

On the first table I am maintining a `parent_id` to store parent folder id.

- 0 is for parent folder id.
- Suppose I have 1,2,3 folders in root
- 4,5 inside 1.
- 6,7 inside 2
- etc.

Media content table is storing contents for each `folder_id`.

Now I need to display the folder structure and contents in CakePHP.

I have gone to the first level of listing. as follows

```
$folderArr = $this->ProjectFolder->find('all',
                        array(                              
                            'conditions'=>
                                array(
                                        'ProjectFolder.is_delete'=>'0',
                                        'ProjectFolder.parent_id'=>$pid,
                                        'ProjectFolder.user_id'  => $userId
                                    ),
                                )
                 );


    $folderContent = $this->ProjectMediaContent->find('all',
                        array(                              
                            'conditions'=>
                                array(                                          
                                        'ProjectMediaContent.project_folder_id'=>$pid,                                          
                                    ),  
                            )
                 );
    //$log = $this->ProjectMediaContent->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
    //debug($log);
    //exit;
    $content  = Array();

    if(!empty($folderContent)){
        $mediapath = $thumbpath = '';
        foreach($folderContent as $mediaContent){
            if(!empty($mediaContent['ProjectMediaContent']['media'])){
                $mediapath = Router::url('/', true).'files/folder/'.$mediaContent['ProjectMediaContent']['media'];
                $thumbpath = Router::url('/', true).'files/folder/thumbs/'.$mediaContent['ProjectMediaContent']['media'];
            }else{
                $mediapath = $mediaContent['ProjectImage']['actual_url'];
                $thumbpath = $mediaContent['ProjectImage']['thumb_url'];
            }
            $parentFolderContent[] = array(
                "mediaId"       => $mediaContent['ProjectMediaContent']['project_media_content_id'],                
                "mediaType"     => $mediaContent['ProjectMediaContent']['media_type'],
                'socialPlatForm'=> $mediaContent['ProjectImage']['image_source'],
                'actualPath'    => $mediapath,
                'thumbPath'     => $thumbpath,
                'socialId'      => $mediaContent['ProjectImage']['social_id'],              
            );
        }
    }
    if(!empty($folderArr)){ 
        foreach($folderArr as $val){
            //print_r($this->getFolderListing($val['ProjectFolder']['project_folder_id'],$userId));die('jj');
            $content[] = array(
                               'Folderid'   => $val['ProjectFolder']['project_folder_id'],
                               'FolderName' => $val['ProjectFolder']['folder_name'],

                              );
        }
    }
```

Project Folder Model as follows

```
class ProjectFolder extends AppModel{
   public $name            = 'ProjectFolder';
   public $primaryKey      = 'project_folder_id';
   public $displayField    = 'folder_name';
   public $actsAs           = array('Containable');

   public $belongsTo = array(
      'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
     ),
   );
   public $hasMany = array(
      'ProjectMediaContent' => array(
         'className' => 'ProjectMediaContent',
         //'dependent' => true,
         //'exclusive' => true,
      )
  );

}
```

ProjectMediaContent Model as follows

```
class ProjectMediaContent extends AppModel{
    public $name            = 'ProjectMediaContent';
    public $primaryKey      = 'project_media_content_id';

    //public $useTable = 'project_medias';
    public $belongsTo = array(
      'ProjectFolder' => array(
          'className' => 'ProjectFolder',
          'foreignKey'=>'project_folder_id'
      ),
     'ProjectImage' => array(
        'className' => 'ProjectImage',
        'foreignKey'=>'project_image_id'
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: So what's your question? Take the [StackOverflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: sorry for the bad way of asking. i am new here and just trying to get each folders and subfolders and those contents.

Comment: How is `ProjectFolder` related to `ProjectMediaContent`? `hasOne`, `hasMany`?

Comment: @ Inigo i have updated the question with models where ProjectFolder hasmany ProjectMediaContent and ProjectMediaContent belongs to ProjectFolder model

Answer (score 0):

The following should fetch all the data you need:

```
$this->ProjectFolder->contain(array(
    'ProjectMediaContent'=>'ProjectImage'
));

$folderArr = $this->ProjectFolder->find('theaded', array(
    'conditions'=> array(
        'ProjectFolder.is_delete'=>'0',
        'ProjectFolder.user_id'  => $userId
    ),
));
```

I would pass `$folderArr` to the view, instead of rearranging the data in the controller.